# Async throwing SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, ecmascript-2017, puppeteer

I'm running a test using the headless Chrome package [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://google.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'})
  // Type our query into the search bar
  await page.type('puppeteer')

  await page.click('input[type="submit"]')

  // Wait for the results to show up
  await page.waitForSelector('h3 a')

  // Extract the results from the page
  const links = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h3 a'))
    return anchors.map(anchor => anchor.textContent)
  })
  console.log(links.join('\n'))
  browser.close()
})()
```

And I'm running the script as: `node --harmony test/e2e/puppeteer/index.js` (v6.9.1)

But I get this error:

```
;(async() => {
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

What could be the problem?

Note: I'm using Vue CLI's official Webpack template:

Comment: You might find http://node.green/ useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out: node LTS (AKA node 6) is not supporting async / await mechanism right now. See : 
[image]

See here for details : https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on my laptop after a lint and it worked perfectly:
[image]

Maybe you have an environment issue.

have you considered removing the semi colon at the beginning of the line? 
It does not look like right programing. Or maybe a webpack issue.

Comment: Which version of node are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest release, currently 8.4.0