# Syntax error in Opera and IE when using the code: async ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, asynchronous, async-await

I have a piece of code that it works with all browsers except Internet Explorer and Opera.

Here is the code: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mz32v7r4/)

```
(async () => {
var InternalURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
var ExternalURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";

    let image, data = await $.getJSON(InternalURL);
    if(data) {
        // Some code
    } else {
        // request failed
    }
    if(!image) {
        let data = await $.getJSON(ExternalURL);
        if(data) {
            // Some code
        } else {
            // request failed
        }
    }
    // Some code
})();
```

In IE in points to syntax error in line `(async () => {`

Any idea why is that and how to fix it?

As I noticed it is a ES6 code, is there anyway to convert a different code that is friendly with older browsers and still gives the same output?

Comment: `async` keyword and `arrow function` ( `=>` ) is ES2017+ ... IE is a 1999 browser ... transpiler is your only option ... Opera should support => in version 32+ and `async` in version 42+

Comment: [async support in browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions). You can use babel to compile your code for supporting older browsers.

Comment: Opera is now based on Chromium and will work mostly as Chrome does, was it not updated in ages?

Answer (score 0):

`async` and `await` are not supported by IE, and are only supported in Opera since version 42 (see [bottom of MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). Do not use ES6 with old browsers - use Babel, or another transpiler to transpile to ES5 (although possibly ES3 in the case of IE?).

Comment: If he wants to use promises rather than callbacks, he can use one of the available libraries, and convert the async/await code to a promise. I'm not sure what Babel transpiles `await` to for an old browser...

Comment: Its duplicate... please follow this one:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066259/async-throwing-syntaxerror-unexpected-token